# JAVA APACHE POI - Work on the copy of master excel

Tags: java, apache-poi

For each request to server create a copy of master excel (In-Memory) , work on it and once the output is fetched , flush the excel . For multiple request , create multiple copies and flush all of those when requests are done processing .

how can we achieve it in JAVA ?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the template file into new file and process.

```
File outputFile = Writer.getFile(outputFileName + "_temp", ".xlsx");
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("template.xlsx"), outputFile);

XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(outputFile);
```

Make sure to keep the template file in CLASSPATH.

Once done you can delete the file.